NuGet Package Creation: Duplicate File Warnings and Proper File Placement in .csproj
I have a project written with C# using .net462 (this cannot be changed becasue it is also used from power apps where the plugin will be added).
I tried to convert PDF to images using PDFIumViewer and PDFtoImage packages from NuGet.
In both cases , through unit tests, everythings works fine.
But when I am trying to update a package with "Plugin registration tool" with my latest version of my code , I always receive an error
the module was expected to contain an assembly manifest Exception from HResuslt :0x8013018 (mscorlib)

I investigate as I could to understand what is happening and I found that in both cases there are also some warnings when I run the rebuild NU5118 and NU5100
NU5118
File 'C:\Users\test.nuget\packages\pdfiumviewer.native.x86.no_v8-no_xfa\2018.4.8.256\Build\x86\pdfium.dll' is not added because the package already contains file 'content\pdfium.dll' [c:\Users\testUser\Repos\TestRepo\Code\src\MyProject\MyProject.csproj]
NU5100
The assembly 'content\pdfium.dll' is not inside the 'lib' folder and hence it won't be added as a reference when the package is installed into a project. Move it into the 'lib' folder if it needs to be referenced. [c:\Users\testUser\Repos\TestRepo\Code\src\MyProject\MyProject.csproj]
I think that the error in plugin registration tool is related somehow with these warnings.
Does anyone faced something similar?
